# Text centering in a 1cm x 1cm cell

Tags: html, css, alignment, cell

I want to create a table with 3 cells. Second cell must be centered and 1cm width by 1 cm height. Text in second cell must be horizontally/vertically centered:

I almost succeeded but even after many attempts I absolutely fail to have the text to appear in the middle of the second cell:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="width:50%;"></td>
    <td style="min-width:1cm;max-width:1cm;border:none">
      <div style="min-height:1cm;max-height:1cm;background-color:red">
        <span class="PageNumber">1</span>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td style="width:50%;"></td>
  </tr>  
</table>
```

How can I have the `span` to occupy full `div` container in order to have centered text (vertical & horizontal) ?

NB: The real-code is more complex and I have just extracted the part that causes troubles (centering text in a 1x1 cm cell).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from the fact that tables should only be used for tabular data, you can achieve what you want using `display:flex`:

```css
.number {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 1cm;
  max-height: 1cm;
  background-color: red;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="width:50%;"></td>
    <td style="min-width:1cm;max-width:1cm;border:none">
      <div class="number">
        1
      </div>
    </td>
    <td style="width:50%;"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Simple and efficiency. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="width:50%;"></td>
    <td style="min-width:1cm;max-width:1cm;border:none">
      <div style="display:inline-block;min-height:1cm;max-height:1cm;background-color:red">
        <div style="margin:0 auto;vertical-align:middle;">
            <span class="PageNumber">1</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td style="width:50%;"></td>
  </tr>  
</table>
```

TL:DR:

I created a div inside your div so the `margin: 0 auto` will cause it to center horizontally and the `display` styles will center it vertically.

More on CSS centering: https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.html

Comment: I ran your code but red cell no longer to appear to be 1cm x 1cm ... it is *autosized* to the text.

Comment: Height is ok but width is not ... I will accept @Pete answer which works fine.

Comment: @CitizenInsane That's cool. Didn't think of flex. I'll upvote Pete too :D